# Passing contours from OpenCV's findContours from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy, boost-python

Have a bit of an unique problem, I am wanting to pass the contours from OpenCV's cv2.findContours() in Python, into a function written in C++, using Boost Python.

I found out what the contours' type is by:

```
>>> type(contours)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(contours[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(contours[0][0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(contours[0][0][0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(contours[0][0][0][0])
<type 'numpy.int32'>
```

This is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np, cv2, py_wrapper
img_file = 'an_image.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_file);
thresh = 100
canny_output = cv2.Canny(img, thresh, thresh*2, 3)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny_output, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
py_wrapper.ndarrays(contours)
```

My thinking is I need to pass the data as a list, then what's inside can be converted from Numpy ndarray into OpenCV Mat using this:
[NumPy ndarray ⇋ OpenCV Mat conversion](https://github.com/yati-sagade/opencv-ndarray-conversion)

And C++:

```
void ndarrays(boost::python::list obj)
{
    NDArrayConverter cvt;
    std::cout << boost::python::len(obj) << std::endl;

    for (std::size_t i=0; i<boost::python::len(obj); ++i)
    {
        PyObject ndarray = boost::python::extract<PyObject>(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, this is what I get:

```
>>> py_wrapper.ndarrays(contours)
12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type _object from this Python object of type numpy.ndarray
```

Any suggestions/insights would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can consider independent c++ program that reads the python output from a file? May be cv::FileStorage?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is part of a bigger project, so the requirements are pretty stringent.

Comment: Which version of Boost is that? Since 1.63, Boost.Python contains a [Numpy extension](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: 1.57 or 58, have to check when I'm on the computer. The version is also a requirement and can't be changed.

Comment: We have Boost 1.57